# PHP connection to Sybase ASE questions

Tags: php, sybase, sap-ase

1 - It is a need to have ASE installed in the PHP server machine for it to connect to a remote Sybase ASE database?

2 - Is there a way to not use the sql.ini (interfaces) file?

3 - Is there a way to connect to a remote Sybase ASE database without any modifications on the PHP server machine?

(I'm running PHP 5.3.2, Windows Server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Using the sybase_connect, if you defined the server hostname in you SQL.ini file, you can connect from how machine to another
2. I don't really know, because I always used the interface file. You can specified a path to you sql.ini file at run time using something like

   putenv ("SYBASE=/usr/local/path_to_ini_directory");
3. Not really. You need a sybase driver on your PHP server

I use mainly unix servers and instead of using the plain Sybase driver/OCS and so on, I usually use the freetds implementation. On Windows, you can install the OCS drivers on the PHP server.